# Pandas copying header names changes blank headers to unamed

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

so I have a csv file that has the headers I need for my dataframe.
So what I am doing is loading both the header file and my data file and copying the headers to my data array, I then save the data array to csv.

here's my code:

```
loader = pd.read_csv('Resources/Headers.txt', sep='\t', header=[0, 1, 2])
ndf = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=loader.columns.get_level_values(2)
ndf.columns = loader.columns
ndf.to_csv('Resources/output.txt', sep='\t', index=False, header=True)
```

The problem is some of the headers are blank (intentionally) but pandas is automatically giving them names like 'Unnamed: 8_level_0'.
How do I stop pandas doing this and leave the column names blank?

Answer (score 1):

You can rename them before saving if the col starts with `Unnamed`:

```
loader = pd.read_csv('Resources/Headers.txt', sep='\t', header=[0, 1, 2])
ndf = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=loader.columns.get_level_values(2)
ndf.columns = loader.columns

ndf.columns = ['' if col.startswith('Unnamed') else col for col in ndf.columns]
ndf.to_csv('Resources/output.txt', sep='\t', index=False, header=True)
```

Comment: This works with single level headers/columns but as I have 3 header levels this gives the error 'AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'startswith''
Do you know how to just change the first layer of column headers or every layer?

Comment: try this ndf.columns[0] = ['' if col.startswith('Unnamed') else col for col in ndf.columns[0]]

Comment: This changes the first column of headers rather than the first row of headers. Sorry I'm having a lot of trouble getting my head around this

Comment: So I've managed to slowest work around, after saving the file with the unnamed headers. I read_csv the file, setting header[0], then using ['' if col.startswith('Unnamed') else col for col in ndf.columns] I set the headers to the correct '' and then saved the file back to csv